# Jquery not changing background-size attribute

Tags: jquery, css, background-size

I am pretty new to this and having difficulty figuring out by my code will not execute the following

```
var h = $( window ).height();

$('.bg').css({

    'height' : h,
    'background-size' : "auto" + h

})
```

More specifically the background-size is not being changed.  The height works great however I want the background-size to look as follow background-size: auto 900px (assuming it gathered 900px as the height).

Am I missing something?

Thank you in advanced.

---

Seems like the below answer worked however did need to add the px as follows;

"background-size" : "auto " + h + "px"

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add space after `auto`:

```
'background-size' : "auto " + h
```

Comment: mmm .. you are faster with 7 sec :) so +1